# Error building Haskell stack project using docker-compose

Tags: docker, haskell, docker-compose, haskell-stack

I'm starting a new Haskell project using stack, and I would like to build and run it using docker-compose, so that I can run it with other applications (db, load balancer, etc ...).

However my stack project is failing to build inside the container.
After running docker-compose up, I'm getting this error

```
...
Step 6/8 : RUN stack build --dependencies-only ---> Running in 6d42f4797edd
Downloading lts-11.10 build plan ...
Downloaded lts-11.10 build plan.
AesonException "Error in $.packages.cassava.constraints.flags['bytestring--lt-0_10_4']: Invalid flag name: \"bytestring--lt-0_10_4\""
ERROR: Service 'be' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c stack build --dependencies-only' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My project structure looks like

```
- README.md
- docker-compose.yml
/be
  - Dockerfile
  - /app
  - /src
  - be.cabal
  - stack.yaml
/fe
  - ...
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: '3'
services:
    be:
        build: ./be
        image: be
        command: stack exec be
        ...
    fe:
      ...
```

My BE Dockerfile

```
FROM haskell:8.2
RUN mkdir -p /app/user
WORKDIR /app/user
COPY stack.yaml *.cabal ./

RUN export PATH=$(stack path --local-bin):$PATH
RUN stack build --dependencies-only

COPY . /app/user
RUN stack install
```

My stack.yaml

```
resolver: lts-11.10
packages:
```

My .cabal

```
...
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                       , aeson
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable be
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                       , be
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

My stack build is working perfectly fine in local, so I guess there could be something wrong with the Haskell image I'm using for the Docker container ?

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a stack bug, which has been fixed in more recent releases.  So, I suspect that docker image has too old of a stack version.

Unfortunately, the Cassava maintainer has refused to merge patches removing a double hyphen from a flag name.  Howeve,r